# C++ struct member alignment and packing requirements on ARM

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, memory-alignment, address-sanitizer

I'm wanting to make a struct form/layout more "defined/fixed" and less "up to the compiler's discretion". The struct layout will be shared when communicated between x86_64 and ARMv7-A architectures. Yes, it's not portable in general, but for this more restricted case, the endianness is the same (and could be converted if decided to be used on a different platform).

**Are there alignment requirements for different data types/sizes on ARMv7-A?** (i.e. misusing them is undefined behaviour)

**Or can it pack them to any alignment?** (i.e. it is all defined behaviour)

**Do some alignments give better performance than others?**

I had been reading on packing/alignment requirements for ARM, but unfortunately I've noticed it's a bit dated relative to my architecture.
http://www.aleph1.co.uk/chapter-10-arm-structured-alignment-faq

I have been using headers like this, on both architectures:

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct foo
{
  uint8_t bar1;        // 1 byte, the 3 padding bytes
  std::array<double,1> bar2;   // 8 bytes
};
#pragma pack()
```

I am using GCC cross compiler for ARM: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9`

When I call `foo abc; abc.bar2.data();`, and compile with `-fsanitize=undefined
-fsanitize=address` produces a runtime error:

```
runtime error: member call on misaligned address 0xbeeb0c44 for type 'struct array', which requires 8 byte alignment
0xbeeb0c44: note: pointer points here
  01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  f4 0d eb be fc 0d eb be  c0 a5 00 00 00 00 db 4b
              ^
/sysroot.../usr/include/c++/5.2.0/array:230:32: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbeeb0c44 for type 'const double', which requires 8 byte alignment
0xbeeb0c44: note: pointer points here
  01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  f4 0d eb be fc 0d eb be  c0 a5 00 00 00 00 db 4b
              ^
```

I like to trust the sanitiser, and it makes me think that's bad. However, if I turn off the sanitisers and crank up optimisation to `-O3`, it behaves okay. However I might just be (un)lucky, and this case of undefined behaviour just appears to work fine. I remember earlier I had the -Wcast-align warning triggered when I did pack(1) instead of pack(4), but I can't remember how I was accessing it to get that triggered. I assume that is also indicating that it was likely undefined behaviour. **Is it true that the address sanitiser and -Wcast-align were indicating undefined behaviours for this architecture, even though it appeared to work?**

**Would it be recommended to increase to pack(8) to fix the undefined behaviour?** It does unfortunately increase the memory usage.

Finally, **is `pragma pack(n)` or `__attribute__((packed))` for each struct entity the preferred way of doing this?** (`__attribute__((packed))` is a GCC extension, and unfortunately can't specify the pack size.)

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a performance penalty for unaligned accesses because for a single access you may have to touch two cache lines.

I guess that the exact reaction to unaligned accesses (slow down or fault) is not defined by the architecture description but might be left to the implementation.

When you just follow the old habit of ordering the fields in a struct by descending size then all today's C(++) compilers will produce the same memory layout. I would suggest that route to save you from grief.

Comment: On ARM whether to fault or not can vary depending on the page table setup; unaligned accesses to strongly ordered or device memory will always fault, even if unaligned accesses to normal memory work. For "normal" applications unlikely to cause a problem, but can be fun in system level software.

Comment: Thanks. However, the order does matter, and can't be arbitrarily ordered. There should be a small checksum at the beginning of the struct, which can't change position.
So the question then becomes: How does one find out the alignment requirements of the implementation's ABI?

Comment: @Isogen74: "Fault" as in page fault / cache miss? Or as in I/O failure?
Please define the terms "strongly ordered", "device memory", "normal memory". Thanks.

Comment: Fault as in page fault (or bus fault); it's often visible as a SIGBUS on Linux platforms, for example. Hard to give a short answer around what they are - I'd recommend looking at the ARMv7-A Architecture Manual Very briefly, "Normal" is what applications normally see for system RAM (allows caching, reordering of reads and writes, merging of accesses, unaligned access). Device memory and Strongly orders are different variations on how you map memory mapped registers, so most things "clever" are off the table (no merging, unaligned, reorder, but Device can be buffered in write buffers).

Comment: For application software you can generally assume you're going to get "Normal" memory, for system software it depends what you are doing.